# Rounding to nearest 100

Tags: algorithm

First number needs to be rounded to nearest second number. There are many ways of doing this, but whats the best and shortest algorithm? Anyone up for a challenge :-)

1244->1200 
1254->1300
123->100
178->200
1576->1600
1449->1400
123456->123500
654321->654300
23->00
83->100

Answer (score 39, accepted):

For input `n`:

```
(n + 50) / 100 * 100
```

using integer division.

Note that many languages/libraries already have functions to do this.

Comment: In JavaScript, this worked for me: 100 * Math.floor((n + 50) / 100);

Answer (score 68):

Ruby's round method can consume negative precisions:

`n.round(-2)`

In this case -2 gets you rounding to the nearest hundred.

Comment: ruby 2.0, for the win on this one.

Comment: Much better. Should be the winner. This is the native answer.

Comment: Learned me something today!

Comment: That is dope af.

Answer (score 8):

```
100 * round(n/100.0)
```

Answer (score 5):

I know it's late in the game, but here's something I generally set up when I'm dealing with having to round things up to the nearest nTh:

```
Number.prototype.roundTo = function(nTo) {
    nTo = nTo || 10;
    return Math.round(this * (1 / nTo) ) * nTo;
}
console.log("roundto ", (925.50).roundTo(100));

Number.prototype.ceilTo = function(nTo) {
    nTo = nTo || 10;
    return Math.ceil(this * (1 / nTo) ) * nTo;
}
console.log("ceilTo ", (925.50).ceilTo(100));

Number.prototype.floorTo = function(nTo) {
    nTo = nTo || 10;
    return Math.floor(this * (1 / nTo) ) * nTo;
}
console.log("floorTo ", (925.50).floorTo(100));
```

I find myself using Number.ceilTo(..) because I'm working with Canvas and trying to get out to  determine how far out to scale.

Answer (score 2):

This will do it, given you're using integer math:

```
n = (n + 50) / 100 * 100
```

Of course, you didn't specify the behavior of e.g., 1350 and 1450, so I've elected to round up. If you need round-to-even, that'll not work.

Answer (score 2):

As per Pawan Pillai's comment above, rounding to nearest 100th in Javascript:
    `100 * Math.floor((foo + 50) / 100);`

Answer (score 0):

Is this homework?

Generally, mod 100, then if >50 add else subtract.

Comment: What the hell Brian! mod and if-then-else that's gonna be really slow. If you're using integers check David's answer. It's a branch-less common way to solve this problem. It works with floating-point numbers as well.

Comment: I myself came up with this answer in Ruby. 

numbers.each {|number| puts number + '->' + number.gsub(/\d\d\d$/,(number[number.size-3,1].to_i + number[number.size-2,1].to_i / 5).to_s+'00')}