# Logical OR between numbers

Tags: javascript

In [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/584948/rounding-to-nearest-100) one answer is the following:

```
Number.prototype.roundTo = function(nTo) {
    nTo = nTo || 10;
    return Math.round(this * (1 / nTo) ) * nTo;
}
```

What does it mean? Why do I need to do this?

```
nTo = nTo || 10;
```

Comment: It means if no `nTo` argument is provided, use an arbitrary `10` instead. It's like a default value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is often used in Javascript for default values.

Logical OR (`||`) returns the first value if truty or the second if the first is falsy.
When a function expects a parameter that is not passed the value the function gets is `undefined` that is falsy. This means that

```
var x = parm || default_value;
```

will use `default_value` in case `parm` has not been passed.

If the value `0` or an empty string `""` is however acceptable as parameter value this wouldn't work because `0` and the empty string are also falsy.

Moreover if the value of parameter can also be `undefined` (meaning `undefined` should be used and not the default) the only solution is to check `arguments.length`.

Comment: Please don't use `default` as the name of a variable, because it is a language keyword...

Answer (score 2):

```
nTo = nTo || 10;
```

Can be realized as short for

```
nTo = nTo ? nTo : 10;
```

which in turn is a short for

```
if (nTo) {
  nTo = nTo;
} else {
  nTo = 10;
}
```

If `nTo` is a non-falsy value then `nTo` will be assigned to `nTo`, otherwise `10` will be assigned to `nTo`.

From http://docs.nodejitsu.com/articles/javascript-conventions/what-are-truthy-and-falsy-values

**List of javascript falsy values**

```
false // obviously
0     // The only falsy number
""    // the empty string
null
undefined
NaN
```