# Trying to round to nearest $5, $10, $50, and $100 when computing the next minimum bid in an auction

Tags: java, algorithm, methods

I'm working on a big program that utilizes a bunch of smaller methods to create a functioning auction system. I'm having trouble with this particular method where I have to raise the minimum bid for an item given the current or "now highest bid"

The instructions are as follows:

If a bid is accepted, then you need to raise the minBid on that item by 5% above the current bid,rounded up to the nearest $5 below $100.00, 
rounded up to the nearest $10 between $100.01 and
$1000.00, rounded up to the nearest $50.00 between
$1000.01 and $10000.00, and rounded up to
the nearest $100 above $10000.00

My main issue is figuring out exactly I can round up by just 5 or just 10, depending on the amount of the bid. Here's my code so far, any help would be greatly appreciated :)

```
public class computeMinNextBid
{
    public static double computeMinNextBid(double currentBid)
    {
        double minNextBid = (currentBid * 0.05) + currentBid;
        if(minNextBid <= 100.00)
        {
            minNextBid = Math.round(minNextBid);
        }

        else if(minNextBid >= 100.01 && minNextBid <= 1000.00)
        {
            minNextBid = Math.round(minNextBid); 
        }

        else if(minNext Bid >=1000.01 && <= 10000.00)
        {
            minNextBid = Math.round(minNextBid);
        }

        else(minNextBid >= 10000.01)
        {
            minNextBid = Math.round(minNextBid); 
        }
        return minNextBid; 
    }

    public static void main(String [] args)
    {
        double currentBid = Double.parseDouble(args[0]); 
        double minNextBid = computeMinNextBid(currentBid); 
        System.out.println("The next minimum bid is: " + minNextBid); 
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you can find the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/584948/rounding-to-nearest-100?rq=1

Comment: You probably want to use mod

Answer (score 2):

The general expression for rounding to *N* (using integer arithmetic) is:

```
x = (x + N/2)/N * N;
```

This *rounds* to the nearest multiple of *N*. For example, for *x* = 45 an *N* = 100, this yields 0 (i.e., it rounds 45 down to 0). For *x* = 55, this yields 100 (i.e., it rounds 55 up to 100).

To round *down* (also known as truncation), remove the "`+ N/2`" part:

```
x = x/N * N;
```

To round *up* to the nearest *N*, use:

```
x = (x + N-1)/N * N;
```

For example, for *x* = 35 and *N* = 100, this yields 100 (i.e., it rounds any *x* between 0 and 99 up to 100).